# Connect two different database in one page

Tags: php, mysql

[image]

The second column, in the Procedures, it says there are no records. It shouldnt be like that. The results in there is from the data from another database. I already have the code for it and if I use include with a different php file with another mysql_connect configuration (from another database), the patient information isnt retrieved like the one seen here:

[image]

I know how to do multiple connections by storing different variables of the two connections.. But its much confusing to me cause its in different include files.

That page in the screenshot is `editclient.php` and i included `editclient_include_inv.php` where the code for the "procedures" section.

`editclient.php`

```
<?


include('header.php');

  if ($id) {
echo "<h1>Edit Medical Records # : $id</h1>";
}
else
{
echo " <h1>Medical Records</h1>";
}


if($submit)
{
//-------------------check user name-----------------------------------------------------
$name = $_POST['name'];

$select = "select first_name from patient where last_name = '".$last_name."';";
$query = mysql_query($select) or die ("Mysql error! It was: ".mysql_error());
$rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($rows != 0)
{

  echo ("<script language=javascript>alert ('Sorry! $first_name is already taken!')</script>");
  echo ("<script language=javascript>document.location.href = 'editclient.php'</script>");

exit;
}
if($name == "admin"){
  echo ("<script language=javascript>alert ('Sorry! $first_name is not a good thing to do!')</script>");
  echo ("<script language=javascript>document.location.href = 'editclient.php'</script>");
exit;

}
//-----------------------------------end check-------------------------------------------
$sql = "INSERT INTO patient (`first_name`, `last_name`,`country`, `address`, `gender`, `telno`, `occ`, `spo`, `occ2`,`cp`, `tel2`, `reff`, `all`, `ill`, `mat`, `frat`, `datetime`, `vs`,`ppe`, `ffup`)
VALUES ('$first_name','$last_name','$country','$address','$gender','$telno','$occ','$spo','$occ2', '$cp','$tel2','$reff','$all','$ill','$mat','$frat','$datetime','$vs','$ppe','$ffup')";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
//echo ("<script language=javascript>document.location.href = 'editclient.php?id=$id&message=Patient $id has been Created!'</script>");
echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
    window.alert('Succesfully Updated')
    window.location.href='sample4.php';
    </SCRIPT>");

}
else if($update)
{

$sql = "UPDATE patient set first_name='$first_name',last_name='$last_name',
country='$country',address='$address',gender='$gender',telno='$telno',
occ='$occ',spo='$spo',occ2='$occ2', cp='$cp', tel2='$tel2',reff='$reff', ill='$ill', mat='$mat', frat='$frat', datetime='$datetime', vs='$vs', ppe='$ppe' ,ffup='$ffup'
WHERE clientid=$id";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
//echo ("<script language=javascript>document.location.href = 'editclient.php?id=$id&message=Client $id has been Updated!'</script>");
echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
    window.alert('Succesfully Updated')
    window.location.href='sample4.php';
    </SCRIPT>");


}
else if($id)
{
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM patient WHERE clientid=$id",$db);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

?>
</p>
<br><font color=red size=4><?php if (isset($_GET['message'])) { echo ' - '.$_GET['message']; } ?></font><BR>
<?

//-------------NEXT PREVIOUS----------------------------------------------------------------------

$sql ="SELECT * FROM patient WHERE clientid < '$id' ORDER by clientid DESC LIMIT 1";

$resultp = mysql_query($sql);
$previousrows = mysql_num_rows($resultp);
while ($prerow = mysql_fetch_array($resultp)) {
$prev=$prerow['clientid'];
}
//echo $prev;

$sql2 ="SELECT clientid FROM patient WHERE clientid > '$id' ORDER by clientid ASC LIMIT 1";

$resultn = mysql_query($sql2);
$nextrows = mysql_num_rows($resultn);
while ($nextrow = mysql_fetch_array($resultn)) {
$next=$nextrow['clientid'];
}
//echo $next;
if ($previousrows == "") {
echo "";
}else{
echo "<B><a href=$PHP_SELF?id=$prev>$prev <- Prev</a> | ";
}
echo "<font size=6><B>$id</B></font>";
if ($nextrows == "") {
echo "";
}else{
echo "<b> | <a href=$PHP_SELF?id=$next > Next -> $next</a></b>";
}
//-----------------end next prev-----------------------------------------------------
?><br><br>
<?php include("inc/nav.inc");?>
<form name="form2a" method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF?>">
   <table width="760" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td class=topHeadrow1 valign="middle" width="50%" colspan="2">
Edit Patient Information:</td>
      <td class=topHeadrow1 valign="middle" width="10" rowspan="20">
&nbsp;</td>
      <td class=topHeadrow1 valign="middle" width="50%">
Procedures:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" align="right">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row["clientid"]?>">
First name:<br>
</td>
      <td valign="top" align="left">
&nbsp;<input type="text" size="20" name="first_name" value="<?php echo $row["first_name"]?>" ></td>
      <td valign="top" width="10%" rowspan="13">
<?
include('editclient_include_inv.php');
?>

      </td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" align="right">
Last Name:
</td>
      <td valign="top" align="left">
&nbsp;<input type="text" name="last_name" size="20" value="<?php echo $row["last_name"]?>"></td>
   </tr>


   <tr> 
    <td valign="top" align="right"> Gender:</td>
      <td valign="top" align="left"><select name="gender">
      <option value="Male">Male</option>
      <option value="Female">Female</option> </select> 
         </td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
    <td valign="top" align="right">  Country:</td>
  <td valign="top" align="left">
      <select name="country" >
        <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
        <option value="Bahrain">Bahrain</option>

<option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option>
<option value="Bhutan">Bhutan</option>
<option value="Brunei">Brunei</option>
<option value="Cambodia">Cambodia</option>
        <option value="China">China</option>
        <option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option>


<option value="Maldives">Maldives</option>
<option value="Mongolia">Mongolia</option>
<option value="Myanmar">Myanmar (Burma)</option>
<option value="Pakistan">Pakistan</option>
<option value="Philippines">Philippines</option>
<option value="Saudi Arabia">Saudi Arabia</option>
<option value="Singapore">Singapore</option>
<option value="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka</option>
<option value="Syria">Syria</option>
<option value="UAE">United Arab Emirates</option>
<option value="Uzbekistan">Uzbekistan</option>

    </select> 

    </tr>

        <tr>
      <td valign="top" align="right">
Tel. no.:</td>
      <td valign="top" align="left">
<input
 type="text" size="20" name="telno" placeholder="###-####" value="<?php echo $row["telno"]?>"></td></tr>
 <tr>
      <td valign="top" align="right">
Occupation:</td>
      <td valign="top" align="left">
<input
 type="text" size="20" name="occ" value="<?php echo $row["occ"]?>"></td></tr>
 <tr>
      <td align="right">
Spouse:</td>
      <td >
<input
 type="text" size="20" name="spo" value="<?php echo $row["spo"]?>"></td></tr><tr>
  <td align="right">
Occupation:</td>
      <td >
<input
 type="text" size="20" name="occ2" value="<?php echo $row["occ2"]?>"></td></tr>



 <tr>
      <td align="right" width="20">
Contact Person(in case of emergency):</td>
      <td >
<input
 type="text" size="20" name="cp" value="<?php echo $row["cp"]?>"></td></tr><tr>
  <td align="right">
Tel. no:</td>
      <td >
<input
 type="text" size="20" name="tel2" value="<?php echo $row["tel2"]?>"></td></tr>

    <tr>
      <td valign="top" align="right" nowrap>
Address:</td>
      <td valign="top" align="left">
<input type="text" name="address" value="<?php echo $row["address"]?>" size="31"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
      <td valign="top" align="right" nowrap>
Reffered By:</td>
      <td valign="top" align="left">
<input type="text" name="reff" value="<?php echo $row["reff"]?>" size="31" ></td>
      </tr>

          <tr>
      <td class=topHeadrow1 valign="middle" width="50%" colspan="2">
Past Medical History:</td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" align="right" nowrap>
Allergy:</td>
      <td valign="top" align="left">
<input type="text" name="all" value="<?php echo $row["all"]?>" size="31"></td>
      </tr> 
      <tr>
      <td valign="top" align="right" nowrap>
Previous illness:</td>
      <td valign="top" align="left">
<input type="text" name="ill" value="<?php echo $row["ill"]?>" size="31"></td>
      </tr>

    <tr>
     <td class=topHeadrow1 valign="middle" width="50%" colspan="2">
<b><font size="4">
Heredo-Familial Diseases:</font></b></td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" align="right" nowrap>
Maternal:
     </td>
      <td valign="top" align="left">
<input type="text" name="mat" value="<?php echo $row["mat"]?>" size="20"></td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" align="right" nowrap>
Fraternal:
     </td>
      <td valign="top" align="left">
<input type="text" name="frat" value="<?php echo $row["frat"]?>" size="20"></td>
      </tr>

<tr>
     <td class=topHeadrow1 valign="middle" width="50%" colspan="2">
<b><font size="4">
Examination:</font></b></td>
      </tr>   
<tr>
      <td valign="top" align="right" nowrap>
Date / Time:</td>
      <td valign="top" align="left">
<input type="text" name="datetime" value="<?php echo $row["datetime"]?>" size="31"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td valign="top" align="right" nowrap>
Vital Signs:</td>
      <td valign="top" align="left">
<input type="text" name="vs" value="<?php echo $row["vs"]?>" size="31"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td align="center" nowrap>
Complain PPE Findings:</td>
      <td valign="top" align="left">
<input type="text" name="ppe" value="<?php echo $row["ppe"]?>" size="31"></td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td align="center" nowrap>
Plan / Management / FF-UP</td>
      <td valign="top" align="left">
<input type="text" name="ffup" value="<?php echo $row["ffup"]?>" size="31"></td>
      </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class=topHeadrow1 valign="middle" width="100%" colspan="4">
<p align="center"><input class="form-button" type="Submit" name="update" value="Update Information"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" width="100%" colspan="4">
<br>
</td>
    </tr>
  </table>


  </form>

<?
}
else
{
//----------------------------begin add client--------------------------------------------------------
?>
<br><font color=red size=4><?php if (isset($_GET['message'])) { echo ' - '.$_GET['message']; } ?></font><BR>

<form name="form2b" method="post" action="editclient.php" onSubmit="return checkPw(this)">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="topHeadrow5" valign="top" width="100%" colspan="5">
<b><font size="4">Patient Information:</font></b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" align="right">
First Name:</td>
      <td valign="top" align="left">
<input
 type="text" size="20" name="first_name" ></td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" align="right">
Last Name:</td>
      <td valign="top" align="left">
<input type="text" name="last_name" size="20"></td></tr>
    <tr> 
    <td valign="top" align="right"> Gender:</td>
      <td valign="top" align="left"><select name="gender">
      <option value="Male">Male</option>
      <option value="Female">Female</option> </select> 
           </td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
    <td valign="top" align="right">Country:</td>
  <td valign="top" align="left">
      <select name="country" >
        <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
        <option value="Bahrain">Bahrain</option>

<option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option>
<option value="Bhutan">Bhutan</option>
<option value="Brunei">Brunei</option>
<option value="Cambodia">Cambodia</option>
        <option value="China">China</option>
        <option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option>


<option value="Maldives">Maldives</option>
<option value="Mongolia">Mongolia</option>
<option value="Myanmar">Myanmar (Burma)</option>
<option value="Pakistan">Pakistan</option>
<option value="Philippines">Philippines</option>
<option value="Saudi Arabia">Saudi Arabia</option>
<option value="Singapore">Singapore</option>
<option value="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka</option>
<option value="Syria">Syria</option>
<option value="UAE">United Arab Emirates</option>
<option value="Uzbekistan">Uzbekistan</option>

    </select> 

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" align="right">
Tel. no.:</td>
      <td valign="top" align="left">
<input
 type="text" size="20" name="telno" placeholder="###-####"></td></tr>
 <tr>
      <td valign="top" align="right">
Occupation:</td>
      <td valign="top" align="left">
<input
 type="text" size="20" name="occ" ></td></tr>
 <tr>
      <td align="right">
Spouse:</td>
      <td >
<input
 type="text" size="20" name="spo" ></td>
  <td align="right">
Occupation:</td>
      <td >
<input
 type="text" size="20" name="occ2" ></td></tr>



 <tr>
      <td align="right" width="20">
Contact Person(in case of emergency):</td>
      <td >
<input
 type="text" size="20" name="cp" ></td>
  <td align="right">
Tel. no:</td>
      <td >
<input
 type="text" size="20" name="tel2" ></td></tr>


  <tr>
      <td valign="top" align="right" nowrap>
Address:</td>
      <td valign="top" align="left">
<input type="text" name="address"  size="50"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
      <td valign="top" align="right" nowrap>
Reffered By:</td>
      <td valign="top" align="left">
<input type="text" name="reff" size="31"></td>
      </tr>

    <tr>
     <td class="topHeadrow5" valign="top" width="200" colspan="5">
<b><font size="4">
Past Medical History:</font></b></td>
      </tr>

<tr>
      <td valign="top" align="right" nowrap>
Allergy:</td>
      <td valign="top" align="left">
<input type="text" name="all" size="31"></td>
      </tr> 
      <tr>
      <td valign="top" align="right" nowrap>
Previous illness:</td>
      <td valign="top" align="left">
<input type="text" name="ill" size="31"></td>
      </tr>

    <tr>
     <td class="topHeadrow5" valign="top" width="100%" colspan="5">
<b><font size="4">
Heredo-Familial Diseases:</font></b></td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" align="right" nowrap>
Maternal:
     </td>
      <td valign="top" align="left">
<input type="text" name="mat" size="20"></td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" align="right" nowrap>
Fraternal:
     </td>
      <td valign="top" align="left">
<input type="text" name="frat" size="20"></td>
      </tr>

<tr>
     <td class="topHeadrow5" valign="top" width="100%" colspan="5">
<b><font size="4">
Examination:</font></b></td>
      </tr>   
<tr>
      <td valign="top" align="right" nowrap>
Date / Time:</td>
      <td valign="top" align="left">
<input type="text" name="datetime" size="31"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td valign="top" align="right" nowrap>
Vital Signs:</td>
      <td valign="top" align="left">
<input type="text" name="vs" size="31"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td align="center" nowrap>
Complain PPE Findings:</td>
      <td valign="top" align="left">
<input type="text" name="ppe" size="31"></td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td align="center" nowrap>
Plan / Management / FF-UP</td>
      <td valign="top" align="left">
<input type="text" name="ffup" size="31"></td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="10%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="90%"><input class="form-button" type="Submit" name="submit" value="Enter information"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </form>
<p>&nbsp;</p>

<?
}

?>
```

`editclient_include_inv.php`

```
<?



if ($num < 1){

$mysql_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_password = "";
$mysql_database = "hmis";
$bd = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die("Could not connect database");
mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $bd) or die("Could not select database");


//printf("<td align=left><font face=Verdana size=1 color=red>There are no Records</font></td>",$num); //prints number

$procedures = "SELECT * FROM incurredcharges WHERE patient_no = '$id'";
$result = mysql_query($procedures);


    if (mysql_num_rows($result) >= 1){


            $procedures = "SELECT
            `incurredcharges`.`procedure_no`,
  `c`.`procedure`

FROM
  incurredcharges
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT `procedure`, `procedure_no` FROM `charges`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT `confinement`, `procedure_no` FROM `confinement`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT `service`, `procedure_no` FROM `ultrasound`
  ) c ON `incurredcharges`.`procedure_no` = c.`procedure_no`
WHERE `incurredcharges`.`patient_no` = '$id'";

            $result2 = mysql_query($procedures);


            echo "<p><table border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=2 bordercolor=#000000 width=100%>";
            echo "<tr align=top>
            <td class=topHeadrow5><b>Procedure #</b></td>
            <td class=topHeadrow5><b>Charge Incurred</b></td></tr>";


        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){

                    echo '
                    <tr>
                        <td>'.$row[0].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row[1].'</td>'; 
                        echo "</tr>";

        }
        echo '</table>';
        }
    else {

        echo "<p><table border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=2 bordercolor=#000000 width=100%>";
        echo "<tr align=top>
        <td class=topHeadrow4><b>There are no Records</b></td></tr></table>";
        return false;
        }
}


?>
```

The second code is for the Procedures column which is retrieved from another database.

Comment: You need to post the code you are using to connect to the db's and the queries you are executing.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted any code, but from the text of your question, I can see that you're using `mysql_connect()` to connect to the database.

The first thing to learn here is not to use the `mysql_xxx()` functions. There are a lot of reasons for this -- for a start, they're deprecated, and also they're insecure.

There are two other APIs built into PHP that you should use instead: either `mysqli` or `PDO`.

But in this case, the even better reason for not using the `mysql` functions is that they make managing multiple DB connections much harder.

On the other hand, mananging multiple DB connections using either `mysqli` or `PDO` is extremely easy.

```
$db1 = new PDO('mysql:host=xxxxx,etc',$user1,$pass1);
$db2 = new PDO('mysql:host=xxxxx,etc',$user2,$pass2);

$db1->query('SELECT * FROM table_on_db1');
$db2->query('SELECT * FROM table_on_db2');
```

So you can keep as many connection objects active as you need, and just use the one that suits for any given query.

You can learn more about the mysqli API here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

And about the PDO API here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Hope that helps.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. Since I used include files its a lot more confusing.

Comment: What exactly did you try? This is the only way to do what you're asking, so if it didn't work, you'll need to fix up the rest of your code to make it work. Bottom line: You need to have multiple connection variables that you can reference throughout your code. It doesn't matter if you've got lots of includes; you need to have those variables, and they need to be accessible, otherwise you can't have multiple databases. In fact, that's best practice even for one DB because both mysqli and PDO require it, and as I said, you shouldn't be using the `mysql` functions any more.

Comment: I changed the include file from the code to a new file where it has the two configurations of the different databases. I checked every mysql_query lines and added the database connection that it corresponds to. The result was just a plain form without any data in it.

Comment: If you're getting a blank page, check your PHP error log (or better yet, turn error reporting on so you can see the error on the page). I'm out of time, so I can't help much more, but I've told you what you need to do, and so has @Sammitch.

Comment: No not a blank page. But the original form but with blank information.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_connect()` returns a connection identifier which you need to store, and then pass in to all of your mysql_* functions. This is how you maintain multiple database connections per-script.

However, mysql_* functions are being deprecated and you should move to either PDO or mySQLi. This would have an added benefit of allowing you to initialize and store separate database objects instead of tracking connection identifiers. ie:

```
$db1 = new PDO('mysql:host=host1;dbname=db1', $user1, $pass1);
$db2 = new PDO('mysql:host=host2;dbname=db2', $user2, $pass2);
```